# "Configuring grup-pc" what should I choose?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a RAID 0 (2x 300GB drives) with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 (58GB ext4 partition, with 5GB swap partition) on them. I have just managed to get my dual boot working.

However, as I went to update some software in Ubuntu Software centre the "Configuring grub-pc" window popped up and shows the following:

- /dev/sda (300069MB; WDC_WD3000GLFS-01F8U0)
- /dev/sdb (300069MB; WDC_WD3000GLFS-01F8U0)
- /dev/sdc (2000000MB; xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) (I know this one is just my external SATA drive)
- /dev/mapper/isw_dcgidgaidc_Win7 (536871GB; isw_dcgidgaidc_Win7)
- /dev/mapper/isw_dcgidgaidc_Linux (63257GB; isw_dcgidgaidc_Linux) (looks like my ext4 +swap)
- /dev/mapper/isw_dcgidgaidc_Linux2 (58012GB; isw_dcgidgaidc_Linux) (just my ext4)

Which of these should I tick to update/install Grub on??

EDIT: If I do:

```
df | grep /$
```

it says:

```
/dev/mapper/isw_dcgidgaidc_Linux2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just select the **ext4** partition where ubuntu is installed.

Comment: So /dev/mapper/isw_dcgidgaidc_Linux2?

Comment: yes you are correct choose that.

Comment: Which I click "forward" it has a screen saying "continue without installing grub?", if I leave it unticked and then click "forward" it takes me back to the list of drives/partitions....

Comment: click space bar which allows you to select the partition.

Comment: Should I select the top 2x drives as well, because the Linux partition is across both of them?

Comment: did you have any seperate partitions for boot,home?If no,then select the root partition.

Comment: I think I chose / and /boot

Comment: it selects the partition or not.

Comment: Ok I selected the bottom two, clicked forward and then it said "Writing GRUB to boot device failed- continue?"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11920/discussion-between-user997112-and-avinash-raj)